# Exit with errorlevel from windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my batch file I have a function where use this command to connect to a remote host:

```
net use %alias%: \\%host%\%root%$ %usrPwd% /USER:%usrName% >> %logfile% 2>&1 || ( call :exitIfError ERROR)
```

I created this function:

```
:exitIfError
setlocal
(set txt=%~1)
if not ERRORLEVEL 0 ( echo %txt% && exit  /B %errorlevel%)
endlocal
goto :eof
```

If I enter an incorrect password is generating the error, but doesn't finish with error and the value of %errolevel% is 0 
instead of 2. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
:exitIfError
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo %~1& exit /B %errorlevel%)
exit /b 0
```

There appears to be no reason to set `txt`

Comment: Or `setlocal` anything for that matter, either.